# How to classify clusters from linear plot

Tags: r, plot, cluster-analysis

Hi I have this dataset (see below)

When I plot I can see clusters. I need a code to classify them as A, B and C the two points in the top left corner are part of the same cluster. Is there any way I can do this?

```
structure(list(RFU1 = c(3654.55151578119, 2256.07773171054, 3451.48127318108, 
3247.53429325864, 3230.68179053305, 3616.83494785465, 3582.60769620167, 
3462.58913470345, 2087.24115058238, 4194.69772466037, 2859.04699086258, 
3266.06621161118, 3677.37149999201, 3766.86073668326, 2536.17565327018, 
2319.62668367909, 1435.50575651976, 2888.93748079533, 3933.3764061777, 
2656.80452198392, 3653.13530768231, 3463.50039794937, 2440.37920079648, 
1495.18927871657, 2957.29937326376, 4143.22406309736, 3874.66214879587, 
3590.55463830271, 2742.1666681013, 2363.48070753678, 4063.02526831426, 
3593.57482697733, 3620.05173320414, 3658.41351428204, 2288.64221539129, 
52.8252658835431, 622.718422126543, 3449.7921496776, 3451.31232328704, 
3183.9226753018), RFU2 = c(711.275372088566, 377.543375987613, 
643.748852098877, 597.660882101699, 194.320351918474, 711.855055314098, 
697.554034231664, 623.465386012266, 4291.66879598214, 864.432106800212, 
4883.19222137258, 653.331600290974, 718.11061174766, 741.28454024865, 
414.008861264183, 4789.37387269961, 2779.43736064139, 5101.6956557223, 
773.810553471156, 4812.4041424854, 700.93534651747, 688.30104530577, 
419.031472847099, 2935.19682769529, 5341.25755595284, 866.736855431337, 
723.402181761772, 699.208943193469, 478.706084705787, 497.088378989427, 
878.773272402471, 692.748925882879, 693.122639578672, 740.353611138638, 
4542.14428046456, 3693.64960411698, 6129.58652320171, 610.602484311436, 
640.625095833564, 556.839865269732)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(3L, 
5L, 7L, 9L, 11L, 17L, 19L, 21L, 23L, 27L, 29L, 35L, 41L, 43L, 
45L, 47L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 53L, 55L, 57L, 59L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 65L, 
67L, 69L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 79L, 81L, 83L, 85L, 86L, 89L, 91L, 93L
))
```

Comment: It may seem like the two points in the diagonal are one group, but if you plot the axes equally, you will see that it's might not be that straightforward to say there's three obvious clusters.

Comment: for example, library(cluster); clus = pam(df,3,metric="manhattan") ; plot(df,col=clus$cluster,ylim=c(0,6000),xlim=c(0,6000))

Comment: most like by hacking around different algorithms etc you can find something that fits what you describe, but does it make sense? clustering is supposed to help you explore the data, not confirm what you think should be there